# Velocity foreach loop is not returning properties of object

Tags: java, foreach, velocity

I have a velocity template `#foreach` loop that's not returning the expected properties from the object I'm trying to get them from: `competitorAttributes` in the ppcThemeData object:

```
#set($ppcThemeData = {
        "competitorAttributes": [
            "Save up to 40%",
            "Set price of &dollar;116",
            "6 attractions from a choice of 9",
            "3 predetermined attractions",
            "Voucher by mail or print",
            "Visit attractions for up to 9 days",
            "No Hop-On Hop-Off bus tour"
        ]
    }
})
```

The loop cycles through each property creating a list item. This loop, however, is not returning anything inside of the `<ul>`. It is also not throwing any errors in the console and the page loads without any issues.

```
<ul>
#foreach($competitorAttribute in $pageTheme.competitorattributes)
    #set($index = $velocityCount - 1)
        <li><span>$competitorAttribute</span></li>
    #end
</ul>
```

Comment: I don't understand what the issue is. And how the two code parts posted relate. Can you post a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$pageTheme.competitorattributes` needs to be: `$pageTheme.competitorAttributes` - the **A** needs to be camel-case.